# Opening product from category url is much slower than loading it from product url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, category-products

So I have a product named A. If I open A from it's own url

> https://mymagentowebsite.com/A.html

it opens fast because it's cached.

However, if I open the product from the category url

> https://mymagentowebsite.com/category1/category2/category3/A.html

It takes much time (like 8-10 seconds) and eventually redirects to

> https://mymagentowebsite.com/A.html

Which could be the causes of this issue and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check the entries in the `core_url_rewrite` table for the corresponding target paths. If you have more redirects for `category1/category2/category3/A.html` and `A.html` pointing directly to the  product detail controller it can be possible that you will have some delay - but 8 - 10 seconds are a lot.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server tuning analysis.